# Sorting ListView Groups?

Tags: sorting, listview, delphi, delphi-xe2

In a ListView, the Items are grouped by the groups "BGroup", "CGroup" and "DGroup" (These are the group headers). Now, when I add a new Item to the ListView and assign a new group with the header "AGroup" to this Item, the group "AGroup" is always inserted at the end of the groups; so the new Groups order is: BGroup, CGroup, DGroup, AGroup. So how can I get the groups sorted in correct alphabetical order? The order should be: AGroup, BGroup, CGroup, DGroup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`ListView_SortGroups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro for this e.g. This macro expects from you to have your own comparison function, defined by the [`LVGroupCompare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775142%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function prototype. In the following code the groups are sorted by the [`Header`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListGroup.Header) property by using the [`CompareText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.CompareText) function, but now it's upon you to build your own comparison.

Forgot to note; whatever you pass to the last `Pointer` type parameter of the [`ListView_SortGroups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro you'll receive in the [`LVGroupCompare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775142%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in the `pvData` parameter, so as this is going to be a group sorting function of a certain list view, it's the best to pass directly [`Groups`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListView.Groups) collection of that list view for easier manipulation.

Since there is no direct way to find a list view group by group ID, I'd use the following helper function for the [`TListGroups`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListGroups) class:

```
type
  TListGroups = class(ComCtrls.TListGroups)
  public
    function FindItemByGroupID(GroupID: Integer): TListGroup;
  end;

implementation

function TListGroups.FindItemByGroupID(GroupID: Integer): TListGroup;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to Count - 1 do
  begin
    Result := Items[I];
    if Result.GroupID = GroupID then 
      Exit;
  end;
  Result := nil;
end;
```

Then you can use this helper method in the [`LVGroupCompare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775142%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function callback this way:

```
function LVGroupCompare(Group1_ID, Group2_ID: Integer;
  pvData: Pointer): Integer; stdcall;
var
  Item1: TListGroup;
  Item2: TListGroup;
  Groups: TListGroups;
begin
  Result := 0;
  Groups := TListGroups(pvData);
  Item1 := Groups.FindItemByGroupID(Group1_ID);
  Item2 := Groups.FindItemByGroupID(Group2_ID);
  if Assigned(Item1) and Assigned(Item2) then
    Result := CompareText(Item1.Header, Item2.Header);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item: TListItem;
  Group: TListGroup;
begin
  Group := ListView1.Groups.Add;
  Group.Header := 'AGroup';

  Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
  Item.Caption := 'Item X';
  Item.GroupID := Group.ID;

  ListView_SortGroups(ListView1.Handle, LVGroupCompare, ListView1.Groups);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you. However, the compiler shows an error in the `ListView_SortGroups` line:

`E2009 Incompatible Types: 'Regular procedure and method pointer`

But when I add a "@" before "the LVGroupCompare": `@LVGroupCompare`, the compiler shows the error in the same line:

`E2036 Variable required`

Comment: And do you have the `LVGroupCompare` defined as a regular procedure (as I have) ? It cannot be a method and shouldn't be nested. I've tested this just with Delphi 2009 (since I don't have Delphi XE2 by hand now), where the compiler was satisfied.

Comment: Yes, I had implemented it as a method. Now using it as a regular procedure it compiles fine, but at run-time when using the macro, I get a `EListError: List index out of bounds (7)`. 7 is the number of groups, but the new group has already been created and assigned to the new item **before** the macro is called.

Comment: I'm quite lost from what you're doing. Using the code I've posted, if you call the `ListView_SortGroups`, the `LVGroupCompare` function is (repetitively) called to compare two existing items, two items with IDs passed by the `Group1_ID` and `Group2_ID` parameters. So I don't want to believe you can get out of bounds with the above code.

Comment: I used your macro in my own program, hoping it would work "out of the box", which apparently it did not, so I now see the error must be in my program. I accept your answer. When I find something to add I will write a comment. Thank you.

Comment: You wrote:
`ListView_SortGroups(ListView1.Handle, LVGroupCompare, ListView1.Groups);`
without the `@` before `LVGroupCompare`.
Both (with and without `@`) compile fine. Which one is correct?

Comment: Ahhh, now it works! Beforehand I used:
`Group := MyListView.Groups.Add;
Group.Header := 'AGroup';
Group.GroupID := MyListView.Groups.NextGroupID;
Item.GroupID := Group.GroupID;
ListView_SortGroups(MyListView.Handle, @LVGroupCompare, MyListView.Groups);`
Now I use this, and it works:
`Group := MyListView.Groups.Add;
Group.Header := 'AGroup';
Item.GroupID := Group.ID;
ListView_SortGroups(MyListView.Handle, @LVGroupCompare, MyListView.Groups);`

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake. I didn't realized that there's no relationship between collection ID and ID of a list view group item in the `TListView.Groups`. See the update for fix...